# INSERT using PDO does not work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Does anyone have any idea why the INSERT is not working? I am working off of a tutorial with identical code, yet I cannot get anything to inserter.

I threw the print_r in there to verify that my POST info is being captured correctly... which it is.  I am losing my mind over here.  Any help would be appreciated.   Thanks

```
    <?php

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['content']) ) {

    include('config.php');

    try{
        $dbh = new PDO(DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);



    } catch (PDOException $e){

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];


    $stmt = $dbh->prepare(' INSERT INTO posts (title, content, created_at, updated_at) VALUE (?, ?, now(), now() ) ');

    $bindings = array($title, $content);

    $stmt->execute($bindings);
    print_r($stmt);

} else { echo 'fail';}

?>
```

Comment: Can you add the output of print_r?

Comment: PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => INSERT INTO posts (`title`, `content`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), NOW() ) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the keyword `VALUES` not `VALUE`

Also, you should really back tick your column and table names. (`)

Comment: wow... i knew it would be something stupid.  Thank you very much and I will use the back ticks.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? you're not saying that because the script echos "fail" are you??

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO posts (title, content, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, now(), now())

Use this as your Insert statement

Comment: is the only difference VALUES? ... instead of VALUE?  Thanks

Comment: Yes ... he should have used VALUES